# Is there a way to assert that a function is recognized as tail-recursive by the compiler?

Tags: haskell, tail-recursion, static-assert

Let's say I've written a function in Haskell and I want to assert that it is tail-recursive and it will be optimized by the compiler. Is there a way to do it?

I know there's a way to do it in Scala with [@tailrec](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/tailrec.html) annotation.

[Example:](http://blog.richdougherty.com/2009/04/tail-calls-tailrec-and-trampolines.html)

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

class Factorial2 {
  def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
    @tailrec def factorialAcc(acc: Int, n: Int): Int = {
      if (n <= 1) acc
      else factorialAcc(n * acc, n - 1)
    }
    factorialAcc(1, n)
  }
}
```

Comment: Tail recursion doesn't have such big significance in Haskell due to lazy evaluation. In fact, in some circumstances tail-recursive functions are actually _worse_ than non-tail recursive.

Comment: Tail recursion optimization happens automatically. It is pretty straightforward for the compiler to automatically detect that a function is tail recursive, under any circumstance I can think of. I don't think it is possible to write a tail recursive function that will not already be automatically recognized and optimized by GHC. I suspect the reason Scala has the annotation is that the tail recursion optimization can lose some call stack info when debugging (whether this is actually bad is a bit debatable, I'd say). Also, what @FyodorSoikin said is important, with regard to lazy evaluation.

Comment: I think the point is not to ensure that the compiler realizes the function is tail-recursive, but to make sure the *programmer* realizes when they have accidentally written a non-tail-recursive function. So, not "please optimize this", which is redundant, but "please notify me if this cannot be optimized". Of course it is rarer to want tail-recursive functions in Haskell, but it is not unheard of, and it could be useful to confirm that you have written one.

Comment: @amalloy - Yes, that's what I meant. Sorry if my post wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for GHC 8.8.2 tail recursion cannot be forcefully asserted by any pragma or keyword.